# Adding UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView with custom cells. In function tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath:) I populate cells from an object's array in this way

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    cell.txtOne.text = array[indexPath.row].firstText
    cell.txtTwo.text = array[indexPath.row].secondText

    return cell
}
```

Now I want to add to the UITextField a UILongPressGestureRecognizer that changes the property .enabled of each UITextField (in this way I can make the UITextField editable).

I have no idea how to do.

I tried adding the UILongPressGestureRecognizer into the Main.Storyboard but I can't catch the action on the UITextField, I can only on the cell.

Can anyone help me?

I use Xcode Version 6.1.1